# Pure HTML Calculator Not Working

Tags: html, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3, calculator

I wanted to try and make a calculator but I'm facing a bug. When I input a number into the calculator, the item I input in shows for a split second but then the whole interface becomes invisible. I tried this for every button but the same result occurs. I also tested adding an `=` sign with no luck of helping the bug. Here's the code:

```
 <div class="fluid-container">
  <form name="calculator">
    <input type="textfield" name="ans" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Result"><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='1'">1</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='4'">4</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='7'">7</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="root()">√</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='2'">2</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='5'">5</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='8'">8</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">x<sup>y</sup></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='3'">3</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='6'">6</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='9'">9</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='0'">0</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='/'">÷</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='*'">x</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='+'">+</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='-'">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div><hr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of each 'button' element, add the attribute 'type="button"'. This will change the behavior of the element. Currently, I think they are treated as submits by default... which will refresh the page and reset the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your button are making get request to the same page. If you need to practice more to develop this application.

For good practicing you have to write a separate javascript code.

You can't develop this calculator using with pure HTML code. Because HTML is not a computing language.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> ### Attributes
>
> #### type
>
> The type of the button. Possible values are:
>
> - `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
> - `reset`: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
> - `button`: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.
> - `menu`: The button opens a popup menu defined via its designated [`<menu>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) element.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)</sup>

Because that attribute is omitted, the default (i.e. *submit*) is used and whenever one of those buttons is clicked, the form gets submitted and thus it appears that the entire interface disappears.

Options to prevent this include:

- set the **type** attribute to *button* for the buttons
- add `return false;` to the in-line Iavascript in the **onclick** attribute of the buttons

See a demonstration below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="fluid-container">
  <form name="calculator">
    <input type="textfield" name="ans" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Result"><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='1';return false">1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='4'" type="button">4</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='7'" type="button">7</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="root()">√</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='2'" type="button">2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='5'" type="button">5</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='8'" type="button">8</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">x<sup>y</sup></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='3'" type="button">3</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='6'" type="button">6</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='9'" type="button">9</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='0'" type="button">0</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='/'" type="button">÷</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='*'" type="button">x</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='+';return false">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='-'" type="button">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type</sub>

Comment: I found that I only had to set the type attributes to button. It worked after. Thanks for the contribution though :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of `button` (in your markup) compared to `input` (used in on-line examples) - Clicking a `button` submits the form. Inputs do not. Update your HTML to use inputs, and you'll see it works.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="fluid-container">
    <form name="calculator">
      <input type="textfield" name="ans" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Result"><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='1'" value="1"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='4'" value="4"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='7'" value="7"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="root()" value="√"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='2'" value="2"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='5'" value="5"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='8'" value="8"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="xy"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='3'" value="3"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='6'" value="6"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='9'" value="9"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='0'" value="0"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='/'" value="÷"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='*'" value="x"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='+'" value="+"></input><br>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="document.calculator.ans.value+='-'" value="-"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div><hr>
```